# Getting albums from Vimeo with php

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to get a list of albums from my account on vimeo, this albums are public so I think I should be able to get them public, the information online is so confusing I guess it has to do with the fact that there is a new version or the Vimeo API (V.3).

This is my code

```
$lib = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);

$token = $lib->clientCredentials('private public');

//var_dump($token);

$access_token = $token['body']['access_token'];

var_dump($access_token);

$lib->setToken($access_token);

$response = $lib->request('/me/albums', 'GET');
var_dump($response['body']);
```

I get this for the var_dump of the $acces_token

```
string(32) "a44c7037d7cca253ae2ad6dd5a30521b"
```

And this for the var_dump from the $response['body']

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> string(52) "You must provide a valid authenticated access token." }
```

So I guess I have to authenticate, but I dont understand this part the info I found is so contradictive.  Usually they add an access_token when they are calling the Vimeo class, but how do I get the access token if I am getting the access token from that Vimeo object first.  I am guessing this for older versions of the api.

Others use a redirect_uri, but this seems more to me when you are required in an app to log with your account.  I just want to display my albums and videos inside of page. The following code is from the github repo of vimeo.php

```
$token = $lib->accessToken(code, redirect_uri);

// usable access token
var_dump($token->body->access_token);

// accepted scopes
var_dump($token->body->scope);

// authenticated user
var_dump($token->body->user);

// use the token
$lib->setToken($token->body->access_token)
```

But it is using objects instead fo the arrays and I dont understand how to get the access token.

Answer (score 4):

I have deactivated your access token. You should not post these tokens in any online forum, particularly public, crawlable forums.

The problem is that the `/me` endpoints rely on an authenticated access token to know who `me` is. The `clientCredentials` tokens are not authenticated, so you need to use the token generated on your app page, or generate one using the redirect workflow. You can find more information in the php library docs, or on the developer site: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication

Comment: it was a test thanks, anyways i realize that i already fix it